# How to resolve if a react query mutation was success or not

Tags: react-query

I have following react query hook

```
export const useUpdateSupplier = () => {
    return useMutation({
        mutationFn: (updateSupplierCommand: UpdateSupplierCommand) => axiosClient.post('/suppliers', updateSupplierCommand).then((res: AxiosResponse) => res.data),
        onSuccess: async () => { await queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: [queries.get_suppliers] }); toastSuccess('Supplier updated.'); },
        onError: (error: AxiosError) => { toastError(error); }
    })
}
```

I call it in a component handler

```
const handleUpdate = () => {
     mutation.mutate({ id: props.supplier.id, name: name, website: website });
     if (mutation.isSuccess) props.handleHideUpdateComponent(); // contains value of last mutation but not the current one
}
```

and I would like to know if the mutation was success or not (to hide the component in my case), but the properties **error**, **isError**, **isSuccess** seems to have value from previous mutation. What am I missing? Should I await the mutation somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `onSuccess` and `onError` callbacks on `.mutate`:

```
const handleUpdate = () => {
  mutation.mutate(
    { id: props.supplier.id, name: name, website: website },
    {
      onSuccess: () => {
        // mutation was successful
      },
      onError: () => {
        // mutation was not successful
      }
    }
  )
}
```

the reason why you see "old" values is because that's how react works. state updates are scheduled and inside an event handler, you will always see values from the render cycle where the event handler was created in your closure.

Comment: Thank you, the idea was to have all the hooks (read and write) in separate file outside the components that call that hooks (not sure if it is a good practice). I solved that by the custom callback function so that hook is more general and might be called from multiple components (even it is probably not good idea to allow changes from multiple components). See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

My colleague came with a following solution. We can add `callback` function to hook and execute it like that `callback?.()`

```
export const useUpdateSupplier = (callbackOnSuccess?: () => void) => {
    return useMutation({
        mutationFn: (updateSupplierCommand: UpdateSupplierCommand) => axiosClient.put('/suppliers', updateSupplierCommand).then((res: AxiosResponse) => res.data),
        onSuccess: async () => { await queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: [queries.get_suppliers] }); toastSuccess('Supplier updated.'); callbackOnSuccess?.(); },
        onError: (error: AxiosError) => { toastError(error); }
    })
}
```

the `callback` function is defined in hook initialization

```
const mutation = useUpdateSupplier(() => DoSomethingAsCallback());
```